# ActiveAndroid abstract class table

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, activeandroid

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a table for an abstract class in ActiveAndroid. For example i could have an abstract class Animal with two concrete classes Dog and Cat. I want to be able to do something like:

```
List<Animal> animals = new Select().from(Animals.class).execute();
```

which would result in 'animals' containing all of the saved Cats and Dogs.
Or:

```
Animal animal = new Select().from(Animals.class).where("name = ?", name).executeSingle();
```

Where 'animal' could be either a Cat or a Dog.
Unfortunately when I do this I get an exception because no table is created for the abstract class Animal.
Does anyone know how I might go about this using ActiveAndroid?

Comment: Can you not use a base class instead of abstraction?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand why you want to do it this way? The whole purpose of an Abstract class is so that you have to use the child class, such as `Cat` or `Dog`. 

Note how you are creating an `Animal animal` object, that cannot be done in Java, however your list before hand can be done, though you'll have to cast to the appropriate subclass before working with the object.

Comment: I wouldn't be creating an abstract 'Animal' in the example above. I would want ActiveAndroid to construct either a Cat or Dog depending on the type of the object when it was originally saved.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ActiveAndroid does not support inheritance of models in that way just yet (https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/14, https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/257).

If you wanted to modify ActiveAndroid here's what you could do:

- Create some kind of annotation that allows you define a model (`Animals`) as something that isn't persisted (refer to `com.activeandroid.annotation.Table`).
- Upon trying to executing queries for that class you could use reflection to determine its child classes and then have it perform that query per child class.
- Then you would basically take the list of results for each query and combine them into a single list and return that.

To be honest I've never seen inheritance in any Android ORM libraries, and personally I don't think it's a good design pattern for models. You may want to reconsider your reasoning for going down this path.

Comment: What would you recommend over inheritance when persisting my model classes? I want to be able to save 'jobs' which may be different types of 'job'. Would I be better off having a separate table per job type then a 'master' table that stored the type of the job and the foreign key to the correct table for that job type?

Comment: @user3265561 What I would do is create the job model in a very generic way. The columns would be JobType and whatever other properties all jobs have in common. It'd also have an AdditionalProperties column which would be a String that contains a serialized JSONObject of any other job specific properties.

Comment: So in that way I could have a generic 'Job' that would be saved to the db, then each subclassed 'RealJob' could override a "serializeAdditionalProperties()" function that would return the json required to rebuild that object when it was deserialized in future.

Comment: @user3265561That could work! As long as you made sure RealJob didn't have it's own table. Though personally I'd probably just keep the one generic Job class and use a bunch of instance methods within it to do different things based on it's type